# Is -はない just another way of saying -じゃありません?

Tags: grammar, meaning

In the sentence:
彼の論文には大した価値はない

Is the -はない another way of saying -じゃありません or -ではない? 
And is it read as wanai or hanai?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would advise you to read up on the differences between all conjugations of the copula だ/である/です and the existence verbs いる and ある.

1. "~はない" (read as "wa nai")　means "~ is not present(Lit: not exist)".

   The `ない`　is the negated form of the existence verb `ある`.
2. "~ではない" (de wa nai) means "it is not ~"

   `ではない` is the negated form of the copula (`である`). It can also be colloquially shorted to `じゃない`. The polite form is `ではありません`, and it's corresponding shortened form is `じゃありません`.

So to answer your question more directly, ~はない is not the same as じゃありません/ではない.