# what is the meaning of the particles in the sentence: 言ったじゃねえかよ。

Tags: particles, colloquial-language

I especially don't understand the grouping of them. I know what the sentence means, but all of those words after 言った are a bit confusing to me. thank you!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18454/9831　and maybe: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40609/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13069/9831

Comment: I wonder why any of those linked threads have not addressed that the じゃ is formally では.

Comment: These threads might be of some help, hopefully... https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/453/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4490/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12846/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > 言った じゃ ねえ か よ
>
> ＝言った **では ない か** （よ）　（＝言った では ありません か）

ねえ in place of ない is a rough word; it should be avoided.

じゃ is a colloquial replacement for では.

This ～じゃないか（よ） is a negative question used as a *tag question*.
It's saying "*I said, **didn't I?***", and じゃねえかよ is said the same thing in quite a rough manner.

じゃないか, on the other hand, is used quite often in casual conversation; **じゃないかな**, **じゃないかと思う**, **じゃない？**, etc., even by itself as a reply to someone's word.

Comment: Please explain what is the reason for the downvoting.